# how to check and give the permission of other section

Tags: android

I want to apply the run time permission for 'Display pop-up windows while running in the background', 'Display pop-up window' and 'Show on lock screen' permission if not given by the user.

Answer (score 0):

not every permission can be acquired in runtime and there is no option for getting mentioned permissions (e.g. `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`) in runtime, you have to pass user to proper settings (e.g. `startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION));`) in which user must enable desired option by itself

Comment: i already given SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW in manifest. but in my case when my screen is locked and notification received, nothing is happening until i am not given the permission of 'show on lock screen' in other permission section. now i want to give it at runtime.

Comment: simply: you can't, not every permission can be acquired in runtime, not these from question